# Is there a variable in Maven that holds the current goal?

Tags: variables, maven-2

In order to invoke the Maven invoker plugin with the same goal that is currently running in my uber-pom, I need a way to pass the current goal into the invoker-plugin's config.

Somethig like

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>${maven.goal}</goal>
          </goals>
        ...
```

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to your question, I am looking for exactly the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven Help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) might help you [get where you want to go](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html).  The ${reactorProjects} variable holds what you are looking for, but perhaps not in precisely the format you are looking to reuse it.

You can view [all the expressions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/expressions-mojo.html) available to you via:

```
mvn help:expressions
```

and then you can [test one of them without the tedium of a pom via evaluation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html):

```
mvn help:evaluate
```

which takes you to a prompt you can use to try expressions.

If I use the help:evaluate and type ${reactorProjects}, I'll get a lot of output, but part of which includes the data you are after:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <inheritanceApplied>true</inheritanceApplied>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <extensions>false</extensions>
    <dependencies/>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
<pluginMap class="linked-hash-map">
  <entry>
    <string>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin</string>
    <plugin reference="../../../plugins/plugin"/>
  </entry>
</pluginMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in my MOJO:

```
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
...
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true)
private MavenSession session;
```

Finally, I was able to get the current goals:

```
MavenExecutionRequest executionRequest = session.getRequest();
List<String> goals = executionRequest.getGoals();
```